# Running out of gas when deploying contract in Ropsten Testnet

Tags: contract-deployment, gas, ropsten

I am trying to create a Fomo3d clone contract in Ropsten testnet for debugging purpose. Here is the code: https://etherscan.io/address/0xa62142888aba8370742be823c1782d17a0389da1#code

But I am constantly getting out of gas error even I specified the maximum gas possible. 
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x854a0172c8ec78c3c5af3c45e7bd05385cb41ad7f635fa5e80c2781ec147b4fd

Comment: What are you using for deployment? Truffle? Remix? Etherlime?

Comment: Please post your code, not a link to it. How do we know it's safe?

Comment: I am using Remix for deployment. The code is too long to paste. I edited the link to point to Etherscan address.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot deploy the smart contract on Ropsten because the block gas limit is not enough for gas used for your contract deployment.

They can do in the main net because the block gas limit of the main net is higher and enough for the contract deployment.